# When does a p.m.f and p.d.f of a function not exist?

Tags: probability

$p(x)=\frac{1}{9}(x-1)$,   $x=2,3,4,5$. Why can this function not be a p.m.f?

$f(x)=\frac{2}{3}(x-3)$,   $2\leq x\leq5$      Why can this function not be a p.d.f?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Is the total mass or probability $1$ in each case; and are the functions non-negative?

In **case $1$, is it true that** $$\sum_{i=2}^5p(x)\overset{?}{=}1$$

In **case $2$, is it true that** $$\int_2^5f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\overset{?}=1$$

> $p(x)$ is not a probability mass function and $f(x)$ is not a probability density function.

Comment: There is no mention of mass or probability

Comment: I have edited to add what I mean, does it look ok to you?

Comment: Actually, in case 2, the integral is 1. However, the integrand takes negative values...

Comment: In case 1, yes it does = 1 since:  p(2)=1/9 p(3)=2/9 p(4)=3/9 p(5)=4/9. When taking the sum of these values it indeed does equate to 1.

Comment: @kate No, it sums to 10/9.

Comment: Far too late at night for this.. sorry for the silly arithmetic mistake! :) x